# Highlight multiple rows in several tables

Tags: javascript, css

I have a page with several rows containing information, made by several users. I'm looking for a way to highlight the all the users rows on mouseover.

This "[Highlight multiple items on hover's condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576167/highlight-multiple-items-on-hovers-condition)" almost solved my problem, but since the classes or id's in my problem are dynamic from a database, and would contain an identifier from the DB and are unique each time. I have not been able to apply it.

Example code: https://jsfiddle.net/3cehoh78/

```html
<table class="testtable">
      <tr id="uniqueIDthatcantbechanged">
        <td class="cellclass">Line 1a</td>
        <td class="cellclass">Sam</td>
        <td class="cellclass">data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="uniqueIDthatcantbechanged">
        <td class="cellclass">Line 2a</td>
        <td class="cellclass">Frodo</td>
        <td class="cellclass">data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="uniqueIDthatcantbechanged">
        <td class="cellclass">Line 3a</td>
        <td class="cellclass">Sam</td>
        <td class="cellclass">data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="uniqueIDthatcantbechanged">
        <td class="cellclass">Line 4a</td>
        <td class="cellclass">Legoman</td>
        <td class="cellclass">data</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table class="testtable">
      <tr id="uniqueIDthatcantbechanged">
        <td class="cellclass">Line 1b</td>
        <td class="cellclass">Sauron</td>
        <td class="cellclass">data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="uniqueIDthatcantbechanged">
        <td class="cellclass">Line 2b</td>
        <td class="cellclass">Sam</td>
        <td class="cellclass">data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="uniqueIDthatcantbechanged">
        <td class="cellclass">Line 3b</td>
        <td class="cellclass">Sam</td>
        <td class="cellclass">data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="uniqueIDthatcantbechanged">
        <td class="cellclass">Line 4b</td>
        <td class="cellclass">Legoman</td>
        <td class="cellclass">data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="uniqueIDthatcantbechanged">
        <td class="cellclass">Line 5b</td>
        <td class="cellclass">Frodo</td>
        <td class="cellclass">data</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

In this example, I want all the rows with "Sam" to be highlighted on mouseover on one of them, so rows 1a,3a,2b,3b.
I was thinking of adding a class to all the Sam rows when generating the tables (Sam has a unique user ID), but how do I then change css that affects all the rows on mouseover (and not just one).
Please note that I cant pre-add css classes for all the unique userID's, this is just an example.

Comment: I assume the user ID is known to the user (i.e. the page delivered to the user). I assume that the page (i.e. JavaScript) can keep track of the rows that the user adds / added. It should then be possible to either use the *user ID* as a class on al* rows the user added or simply add a generic class (indicating ownership) on them.

Comment: Is the use of jQuery allowed?

Comment: Easiest thing is use them as a data attribute.... had whatever is spit out a data-name="foo" and than you can easily select the elements. Seems weird that you can not alter the code that spits out the table to alter it slightly. Without that, you either need to do an expensive contains() selector or loop over the table on page load and set the attribute

Comment: @domdom, this would be a view that is presented to all users, so who you are logged in as doesnt really matter.

Comment: @kevinb. jQuery is fine.

Comment: @espascarello I can alter the table, the only thing that can be altered is the tr id (id="uniqueIDthatcantbechanged"). I can include almost whatever I want from the DB, I was thinking the userid would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution with JQuery https://jsfiddle.net/3cehoh78/5

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $( "tr" ).hover(function() {
     var search = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();

   $( ".highlight" ).removeClass("highlight");


     $("tr:contains('"+search+"')").addClass("highlight");
  }); /* END HOVER */

}); // end document ready
```

Comment: Nice, this seems to be doing the job, I am a bit worried that it may be to heavy, since there is a lot of data in the page. I'll try it out tomorrow and see. Would it be easier if I added some unique value to the row? e.g. userid from the database?

Comment: Performance wise the best would be to give your tr a class with the user id <tr class="SamsID123456">. Class because Sam can have multiple rows and IDs would only be allowed once. And then instead of Doing a Search through the DOM you just highlight all rows with that class on hover.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3cehoh78/7/
Example will work for SAM at the moment

Comment: Thanks, the second solution worked like I wanted :-)
(The first one highlighted way to many other things on the page :p )

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution without using jQuery and co: https://jsfiddle.net/3cehoh78/3/

```
var rows = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.testtable tr'));

rows.forEach(function(row) {
  row.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    resetHighlighting();
    var name = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').textContent;
    rows.forEach(function(r) {
      if (r.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').textContent === name) {
        r.classList.add('highlighted');
      }
    });
  });
});

function resetHighlighting() {
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    row.classList.remove('highlighted');
  });
}
```

Comment: Nice, this seems to be doing the job, I am a bit worried that it may be to heavy, since there is a lot of data in the page. I'll try it out tomorrow and see. Would it be easier if I added some unique value to the row? e.g. userid from the database?

Comment: Why not mark it as accepted answer ;-)

Sure, adding a unique marker to the rows belonging to the same group would be faster. You could spare the selector for the correct child column, and the use of textContent, which might be expensive in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using vanilla-JavaScript.

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');

var highlight = function () {
    // take this person's name from the 2nd cell
    var name = this.parentNode.children[1].innerHTML;
    // highlight cells with same name
    tds.forEach(function (td) {
        var tr = td.parentNode;
        // compare other's person name with this person name
        // highlight if there is a match
        tr.classList.toggle('highlight', tr.children[1].innerHTML === name)
    });
}
// attach an event listener to all cells
tds.forEach(function (td) {
    td.onmouseover = highlight;
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/amxtm6q0/)

Comment: Nice, this seems to be doing the job, I am a bit worried that it may be to heavy, since there is a lot of data in the page. I'll try it out tomorrow and see. Would it be easier if I added some unique value to the row? e.g. userid from the database?

Comment: @ThisIsMe If you are going to use a unique value for each `tr`, then it cannot be stored in an `id` attribute as they are meant to be unique (appear once). I normally store database IDs in [HTML5 data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) e.g. `data-id`. This with a combination of caching your `tr`s as done in my example (first line) and alex3683's may increase performance. But then again, sometimes the clean and short way is better like in Tom's.

Comment: @ThisIsMe This [Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/w5gye6ay/) would be a revision if you were to use data-attribute with an ID.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for however I ran into issues with the "forEach" with error message "foreach is not a function". So I went with the second solution from Tom.